# ¿Como poner varios botones de ver mas en productos de tienda?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una web para una tienda propia por motivos de que la descripción de Productos es extensa los oculte y solo deje el boton Más Info... pero el boton mas info solo me sirve en el primer item alguien sabe como resolverlo?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porque estas usando id y el id debe de ser unico.  Necesitas usar clases en lugar de ids.

Comment: Con clases no sirve ninguno....

Comment: Si usas [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), la función te va a devolver el primer elemento en el DOM que encuentre con ese **id**. Si tienes x elementos más adelante, no los tomará en cuenta. Cuando buscas repercutir en varios elementos, es preferible usar clases. En este caso, utiliza otra función de búsqueda como [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) o [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)